# Cannot resolve path in vue (using webpack template)

Tags: webpack, vue.js

I'm using vue webpack template.
I have a component with its own styles located in a separated file (say, style.scss in /components/my-component/)

I refer to another .scss using `@` alias like this:

`@import "@/assets/scss/variables.scss"` and webpack couldn't resolve it. So now I have to use this instead:

`@import "../../../assets/scss/variables"` which is bad.

Basically the error says it couldn't resolve this import. I came from here: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/issues/328, just want to keep a global .scss file with variables which I will be able to use in local component styles

Comment: what does the "@" resolve to in your webpack config? Also what extensions does it resolve?

Comment: It resolves to "src" folder. Hm, I've just found out that it did not resolve .scss files (extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json']), so I added this extension (extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json', '.scss']) but it still does not work

Comment: Just do `@import "~@/assets/..."`

Comment: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader#imports